# JavaFX : where to put portable database file for application

Tags: ms-access, architecture, javafx-8, self-contained

I am designing a JavaFX application with MS Access database for both Windows and Mac Platforms. My local friends suggests that I place the database file under **"user.home"** folder. Then, the database would be under **"C:\Users \
 {Username}"** folder. But, would it be accessible for another user of the windows or mac?

---

And one more confusion, is it possible or considered best practice to deploy JavaFX application to for all users of the system. I have only found out that JavaFX self-contained applications are all installed for one user only.

Comment: I think the answer will depend on where and how you are deploying the app as well as the nature of the data itself.

Comment: With regards to: "is it possible or considered best practice to deploy JavaFX application to for all users of the system".  That also depends upon the application and your desired deployment mode for it.  There is no best practice, choose what is best for the app and your users.

Comment: Self-contained applications can be installed system wide for certain packaging types.  I encourage you to read the documentation on [installable packages for self-contained applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#A1324980) very carefully if you wish to understand the deployment options available for this deployment method.